# Dynamic key with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl, bundle, resourcebundle

I create a list from json in javascript and append it to a list in jsp. While creating list items I want to get some information from resource bundle dynamically. My code is like below, I couldn't get resources, anyone can help to solve this problem?

```
$.ajax({
    url     :   '/api/getlistitems',
    success :   function(result) {
        if(result.success) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(result.listItems, function(idx, item) {
                var link = item.link;
                var name = item.name;
                var target = item.target;

                items += '<li><a href="'+link+'" target="'+target+'"><i class="entypo-monitor"></i><span><fmt:message key="'+name+'" /></span></a></li>';
            });
            $('#main-menu').append(items);
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSTL markup is evaluated by the container before the page is sent to the client for rendering, so using the format tag assuming it will evaluate once the AJAX call returns is erroneous. You would be better off formatting the key on the backend.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I solved my problem doing in server side. I wonder about it is possible or not in client side, because if I put `<fmt:message key="SomeKey" />` like this, it shows correct value.

Comment: That would work, but every list item would have the same link text as a result. By the time the browser receives the page, the markup will look like so: 
`items += '<li><a href="'+link+'" target="'+target+'"><i class="entypo-monitor"></i><span>Value for key 'SomeKey' in bundle</span></a></li>';`

Comment: Yes, your answer is true but as you said every list item have the same link text. I don't want same link text. I want to create bundle dynamically, I guess it is not possible for now.